# Fonts not loading in firefox

Tags: firefox, webfonts, truetype

I come across this problem all the time where my fonts work in every browser except Firefox. I have multiple sites that use multiple fonts all hosted on the same Cloudfront instance. Searching is pointless because every result is about setting up my CORS settings which work perfectly fine for every other browser and font file.

Currently I have a font file that shows up in the network tab as a 200 request and going directly to the file downloads it for me but I still get

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "veneerregular" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://example.com/fonts/CZ/veneer.ttf
```

in the console.

Here is my @font-face declaration

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'veneerregular';
    src: url('/fonts/CZ/veneer.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/CZ/veneer.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/CZ/veneer.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/CZ/veneer.svg#veneerregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I have also run this program against the ttf fonts to flip an embeddable flag so they will work in IE http://carnage-melon.tom7.org/embed/

The only solution that seems to work is to provide data-uris for the fonts but that creates HUGE css files which I don't want. Is there something I am missing? where else should I be looking? Seems like every 2 weeks some font stops working on firefox.